# How to add checkboxes to a list in html/django

Tags: html, django, checkboxlist

I am developing a django/html application where I have a table of data. I have to make a way for my users to delete multiple rows in a table. Therefore, I have decided to add checkboxes in a list.

I know that I can include it as

```
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="item1" /></td>
<td>Item1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="item2" /></td>
<td>Item2</td>
</tr>
```

for each item. Then in the end, I can add:

```
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete Items" />
```

But this will mean that I will have to enclose my list within a `<form></form>`
Is this an ethical way of doing it?

I want to add this feature to my site but I also want to do it in the most professional way. Can anyone tell me if I am going in the right direction?

Comment: Ajax requests with post data.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use Django, one way would be to take advantage of what Django provides for forms.
Here are the examples from the official doc, for version 1.10:

-for the radio buttons:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/#widgets-inheriting-from-the-select-widget

-for the form:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django

A django form uses the form tag.